# How much waterproofing spray to apply to my softshell jacket

Tags: clothing, waterproofing, rain-gear

I have a Showers Pass Portland Rain Jacket.  The manufacturer recommends using Nikwax TX Direct Spray On to maintain waterproofing properties. How much should I apply to the jacket? How do I know if it's too much or too little?

Relevant Links:

[Jacket Care Instructions](http://www.showerspass.com/care-instructions)

[Nikwax Tx Direct Spray](http://www.nikwax.com/en-us/products/productdetail.php?productid=265&activity)

Comment: I would follow the directions printed on the bottle (which will usually say "don't saturate" or "thoroughly saturate and let dry" depending on the product.)

Comment: Unfortunately the bottle, nor the website for Nikwax mentions any measure of quantity or method of application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Nikwax link you provide:

> For best results remove all non-washable parts and always clean
>   item(s) first with Nikwax Tech Wash®. No need to dry item(s) before
>   waterproofing.
>
> - Protect working surface and lay clean wet fastened garment flat.
> - Hold bottle 15 cm/6 inches away from garment.
> - Apply evenly to outside of fabric.
> - Wait for 2 minutes. Remove any surplus product with a damp cloth.
> - Check carefully to ensure no areas have been missed.
> - After several minutes check for and remove any surplus product with a damp cloth.

Sounds to me like you should spray in on evenly almost to the point of saturation, and remove any excess... (excess is usually the result of over-saturation).

I suspect there is not any hard-and-fast rule, otherwise I imagine they would be more specific.

I'm a fan of more-is-better approach (... to life).

If you use too little, you'll probably notice next time you wear the thing.